# How do I texture crates like this?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to make a Crash Bandicoot Fan Game But I encountered a problem texturing the ever-so famous crates... I cant get the texture to have the inner box be the 128x128 cartoony wood texture while having the diagonal planks be individual planks and the like

I tried UV map Unwrapping but the map always comes back a mess
can someone give me some ways of texturing the way I want?

here is what the crate looks like...
[image: here is what the crate looks like...]

Comment: please give a example of what kind of result you want in uv/texture....

Comment: https://www.crashmania.net/images/encyclopedia/objects/crates/description.jpg

Comment: are the objects (the wood planks) joined into one object? can you show how the current uv map looks like?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XAKqHUG

Comment: ok you need to mark some seams some edges of the model, and then re-uvmap...

Comment: Hi @JBmodelHopper welcome :) It is best practice on this site to add any new information directly into your post [as an edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/199429/edit) so that other users will see it when viewing your Q. There are many users who do not look at the comments here. :)